# Excel multiplying different cells and different rows and suming them up

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

i got a long sheet and i need to mutiply row 2 from AE to CJ with row 2033 AE and CJ and every column cell in AE to CX needs to be summed up. I tried =(AE2*AE2033)+(AF2*AF2033)+.. and so on. but when i wanted to apply it to every row a draged the little + sign but it ended up as =(AE3*AE20334)+(AF3*AF2033)+..
Is there some solution for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use the following formula(fixed line 2033):

```
=(AE2AE$2033)+(AF2AF$2033)+..
```

Here's a simple example:

[image]

Comment: That worked like charm, thank you. Best regards